# Control Report Background Image Conditionally with Multiple Reports Issue (RDLC) Dynamics NAV

Tags: background-image, rdlc, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I was able to control the display of my background image when i do run 1 report. But when i am setting a filter to print multiple reports at once, the report background image do not shift dynamically. Instead i am getting the same background image each time. Is there a solution to overcome this issue.

My background image is placed in the report properties where i have my if statement

Switch statement

```
=Switch(
Code.GetData(39)="S1","EL3",
Code.GetData(39)="S3","EL2",
Code.GetData(39)="S8","EL1"
)
```

Comment: Something wrong with your if statement. Can you post it?

Comment: added, please note that i am setting the background image on the report properties section. Do NAV run only once the report properties ? thats why i am getting only 1 type of image when printing multiple reports using filter

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple reports". Is it different report objects or one object that runs multiple times for different records or one object that outputs multiple sheets for different records?

Comment: I have only 1 object. But when I run the report for example Sales Invoice, on the request page, i filter on example: 001..009. But I am having the same background image, because NAV does not trigger a new background image for each Sales Invoices. I did place the background image in the Report properties

Answer (score 0):

Report Properties are only evaluted once per Report. There are two ways to handle your requirement:

1. Create a List(Or Table) in the report, in which you group by the primary Key (Sales Header No.). Put all your content in this list, set the background of the list.
2. Create one Report per Sales Header. In NAV use your own Filterpage to loop the Sales Headers and call your report once per Report (meaning 9 calls for your example 001..009).